# How to make Jenkins automatically add webhook for Pipeline job?

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, webhooks

I have added credentials for Jenkins to be able to add a webhook. For that I did the following:

1. Generated personal access token on GitHub with `repo` and `admin:repo_hook` scopes.
2. Added `Secret text` credentials with corresponding token.
3. Added GitHub Server with credentials from the previous step in `Manage Jenkins > Configure System`.

But then when I create Pipeline job, I see in the system log:

```
GitHub webhooks activated for job p1 with [] (events: [PUSH])
```

With Freestyle project I get:

```
GitHub webhooks activated for job fsp1 with [GitHubRepositoryName[host=github.com,username=user,repository=repo]] (events: [PUSH])
PING webhook received from repo <https://github.com/user/repo>!
```

For Freestyle project I did the following:

1. On *Source Code Management* tab chose *Git*, specified repository URL and credentials (Username with password).
2. Checked *GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling*.

For Pipeline job:

1. Checked *GitHub project* and specified repository URL.
2. ￼Checked *GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling*.

What am I missing?

Comment: Link to your [issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45120).

Comment: I'd guess the behavior stems from method `parseAssociatedNames(Item item, Collection<GitHubRepositoryName> result)`, in class [GitHubRepositoryNameContributor](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-plugin/blob/93d40692ff3866705175624e93ec584d4ac88132/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/jenkins/GitHubRepositoryNameContributor.java). There are conditions on the type of `Item` which very much could lead to such problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it add the webhook (after creating a pipeline):

- run the pipeline once manually
- reregister the webhooks (Manage Jenkins > Configure System > GitHub plugin > Advanced (with a pencil mark) > Reregister hooks for all jobs)

It is a known issue. You can look it up here: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-37217

Comment: You're a genius. Still, Jenkins... It kind of... makes me sad? It looks like GitHub integration is broken. And I ran into 4 issues trying to create a pipeline...

Comment: Thank you for pointing to this well hidden button, as @x-yuri said that should work automatically, but this is a nice workaround!

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue.
I dont know why but It become well after run the job from blueocean.